# Shorthand for user home directory using parallel-scp

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to upload the same files to a list of hosts using parallel-scp. The files need to go into each hosts separate user home directory: eg. one host looks like this: /home/host1user/www/ another like this /home/host2user/www/ and yet another like this /home/anotheruser/www/

The servers.txt file looks like this:

```
12.123.12.123 host1user

12.123.12.124 host2user

12.123.12.125 anotheruser
```

I've tried using this line:

```
parallel-scp -v -e error -h servers.txt ./testfile.txt ~/www
```

Doing this throws an error saying that

"scp: /home/localusername/www: No such file or directory"

which makes sense.

But, how do I get the correct username in the target directory?

Comment: As the man page says, parallel-scp is *useful for operating on clusters of homogenously-configured hosts*. Your hosts aren't configured homogenously.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I missed that part of the man.

Comment: Can't you create a symlink from the same place on all the machines?

Answer (score 1):

Put the following into servers.txt

```
    host1 user1
    host2 user2
```

Your script can be something similar to this:

```
while read hostname, username; do
    scp testfile.txt $username@$hostname:/home/$username/www &
    sleep 10
done < servers.txt
```

The "&" after the scp command puts it in the background so that you can launch another scp without having to wait for the previous scp to complete... allowing you to do multiple scp in parallel.

The `sleep 10` is to prevent you from launching way too many scp processes in a short amount of time, especially if you do that to the same destination server, your connection will be terminated because it's considered an attack to that server.

Edit the sleep command to the number of seconds to wait accordingly... but if you have only a small number of servers/files then you don't even need it.